# how to insert results from dynamic openquery into a existing table?

Tags: t-sql, insert-into, openquery

How can I insert the result of below dynamic openquery into an existing table

```
  DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @VAR char(2)
  SELECT  @VAR = 'CA'
  SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,''SELECT * FROM pubs.dbo.authors WHERE state = ''''' + @VAR + ''''''')'
  EXEC (@TSQL)
```

I tried Insert into but didn't work.

```
    INSERT INTO TableA 
    SELECT *
    FROM (EXEC (@TSQL))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @VAR char(2)
SELECT  @VAR = 'CA'
SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,''SELECT * FROM pubs.dbo.authors WHERE state = ''''' + @VAR + ''''''')'

INSERT INTO TableA
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in the dynamic string to avoid the INSERT EXEC statement

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @VAR char(2)
SELECT  @VAR = 'CA'
SELECT  @TSQL = 'INSERT INTO TableA SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,''SELECT * FROM pubs.dbo.authors WHERE state = ''''' + @VAR + ''''''')'

EXEC (@TSQL)
```